# "tasklist" command not working in wince 6.0

Tags: windows-ce, command-prompt

I wanted to see the list of process running in windows ce 6.0 machine. In the command window i typed "tasklist" command, it showed Cannot execute tasklist.exe. Is there anyother way to see the list of process running in the machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no command line tool for this included in the OS. You can list the tasks remotely (using platform builder task list, "gi proc" debug shell command or using the process list remote tool) or you can search for one of the Windows CE task managers available on the net (some are working on a specific architecture, other require the .NET runtime etc.).